# How to save id in controller?

Tags: php, yii

I have a `action` which I am calling twice:

```
Controller.php
UserController extends Controller {
    public actionCopy($id = false){
    
    if($id){
    //redirecting to a view
    }
    else{
    //redirection to a different view
    }
    
    
    }
}
```

I am getting a `id` first then from `first view` I am again coming to `Copy action` with no id so else part is running now but in this I want to get the `$id` which I get from first request.

I have tried to define a global variable in controller like:

```
Controller.php
    UserController extends Controller {
public $user;
        public actionCopy($id= false){
        
        if($id){
    $this->user = $id;
        //redireting to a view
        }
        else{
        echo $this->user ;// but it has nothing
        //rediredtion to a differnet view
        }
        
        
        }
    
    }
```

and set it like this.

I know that `if condition` is not executing so `$id` has no value but I set `$this->user` first time then why it has no `value`.

Comment: You can try using cookies or session variable

Comment: You can use all the normal PHP ways of passing around data such as `$_POST, $_GET, $_SESSION, $_COOKIE` etc... (using vanilla PHP or Yii syntax). Which one to use depends on your application structure and how the user is moving between the two actions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just try this,

```
class UserController extends Controller {
    public actionCopy($id = false){     
        if($id){
            //set up a session here
            Yii::app()->session['_data_id'] = $id;

            //remaining code here               
        }
        else{
            $id=isset(Yii::app()->session['_data_id'])?Yii::app()->session['_data_id']:NULL; // the id you want from previous request
            if($id!=NULL){
                //remaining code
                unset(Yii::app()->session['_data_id']); //clear it after use
            }
        }
    }
}
```